# In Drupal 6, what's the quickest way to set up a WYSIWYG editor with code syntax highlighting and image upload?

Tags: drupal, syntax-highlighting, wysiwyg, ckeditor, image-upload

I've seen numerous posts in random places about how to set up a WYSIWYG editor for Drupal 6. I've had luck with CKEditor and FCKEditor via the WYSIWYG Drupal module. All is well there, but I hit a breaking point when I try to add on syntax highlighting and image upload functionality. Any procedure I try is very cumbersome and ends up not working (the last one I tried was using CKEditor + WYSIWYG + GeSHi Filter (with the hack) (described [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node/65398#comment-198803)).

I can't get any combination to work properly so far and there are too many variables/combinations to try. Does anybody have experience with a solution that just works without too much hassle?

Comment: Image upload is not too dificult, is it getting image upload and systax highlighting to work togeher which is causing you greif?

Comment: Something like that... my problem was this: I know for a fact that image upload and syntax highlighting in a WYSIWYG editor are possible in Drupal, but there are too many options out there for implementing those features (many of which I couldn't get working). Until I found the Clifford Meece article, I couldn't find a step-by-step procedure of how to have a WYSIWYG editor with these capabilities in Drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great blog post that almost answered my question [here](http://cliffordmeece.com/content/drupal-wysiwyg-tinymce-syntaxhighlighter-redux). There, Clifford Meece gives step-by-step instructions on how to set up the WYSIWYG modules with TinyMCE and Syntaxhighlighter. He also walks you through adding a few smaller modules that fix some usability issues.

Afterwards, I installed the [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) and [IMCE WYSIWYG Bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) modules right in my sites/all/modules directory. After following the instructions in the IMCE modules readme.txt, I was able to use my WYSIWYG editor successfully with syntax highlighting and image upload features working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck with FCKEditor and CKEditor and IMCE (together with Image Upload, I think). You have to set IMCE as the file manager in [F]CKEditor config.

Answer (score 1):

Just go for the [WYSIWYG-api](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg). And then use TinyMCE. In addition to that, install the [imce](http://www.pythian.com/news/7129/text-vs-varchar/) module. Then install [IMCE-bridge](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg)  to connect both

The code-highlighting, however, is a different problem. I am not aware of a WYSIWYG-editor that has proper code-hightlighting-support. 
(Actually, I am not aware of a proper WYSIWYG-editor in the first place, but that is a whole different story).